# imgAreaSelect JQuery Plugin Resizable Div's Minimum's Width and Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a re sizable div generated by a Jquery Plug-in.It's purpose is for the cropping functionality. Below is the Jquery plug-in's link:

http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html

HTML Code:

```
<div class="imgareaselect-border4"></div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
$('#img_captured').imgAreaSelect({
    handles: true,
    aspectRatio: "1:1",
    disable: false,
    hide: false,
    show:true,
    minHeight: '140px', //Set it's minimum height
    minWidth: '140px'   //Set it's minimum width
});
```

It has a way of setting it's minimum height and width, but doesn't work with me. I don't know what's wrong, so my last resort is to do it manually. I tried using the css code below but doesn't work. How can I limit it until it's dimension is 140px x 140px?

```
.imgareaselect-border4
{
    min-height: 140px;
    min-width: 140px;       
}
```

Comment: Do you want to keep it from being bigger or smaller than 140px?

Comment: It's actual size is 320px x 240px. I want it to limit from being smaller than 140px x 140px.

Comment: Are you using the jquery ui plugin?

Comment: No, But it's almost the same. Im using this plug-in : http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html . It has a way of setting it's minimum height and width, but doesnt work with me. I dont know what's wrong so my last resort is to do it manually.

Comment: Can i see your javascript. Solving this with css isn't going to work the way you want. You'll get add dragging behavior, etc.

Comment: Also, you should rename this question to something about imgareaselect and maxwidth/maxheight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments for maxHeight and maxWidth in imgareaselect don't use strings but integers

```js
$('#img_captured').imgAreaSelect({
    handles: true,
    aspectRatio: "1:1",
    disable: false,
    hide: false,
    show:true,
    minHeight: 140, //Edit here
    minWidth: 140   //Edit here
});
```